# Google Maps iOS API markers not clearing or creating new markers

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have been working with the Google Maps API for iOS, and I am trying to recreate the positions of markers after getting an array of new positions/locations.

Here is my code for the Google Maps:

```
- (void)loadView {

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m


[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
                                                        longitude:locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude                                                                 zoom:13.2];

mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.delegate = self;

self.view = mapView;
[mapView clear];
[self createMarker];

}


- (void) createMarker {

NSLog(@"createmarkers called");
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSMutableArray *lat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *lng = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *markers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *businessArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int x = 0; x < [appDelegate.businessArray count]; x++){
    [businessArray addObject: [appDelegate.businessArray objectAtIndex:x] ];
}

for (int x = 0; x < [appDelegate.geocodedLatArrayGlobal count]; x++){
    NSNumber *latCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[appDelegate.geocodedLatArrayGlobal objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];
    [lat addObject: latCoord];
}

for (int x = 0; x < [appDelegate.geocodedLngArrayGlobal count]; x++){
    NSNumber *lngCoord = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[appDelegate.geocodedLngArrayGlobal objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue]];
    [lng addObject:lngCoord];
}


for (int x = 0; x < [businessArray count]; x++){


    double latitude =[[lat objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue];
    double longitude =[[lng objectAtIndex:x]doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude) ;
    GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    marker.title = [[businessArray objectAtIndex:x]valueForKey:@"name"];
    marker.snippet = @"123";
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greenPin.png"];
    marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
    [markers addObject:marker];

}

}
```

If I load the view for the first time, the markers are being created. However, the second time with a new set/array of lat/long coordinates does not load.

The loadview method is being called, and the [mapView clear]; should be called, but it isn't clearing the markers on the mapview. The next problem is that the new markers are not being created, but I suspect that both these problems have to do with the same thing.

Any tips on why the map view won't clear? Thanks in advance